# Pythonanywhere: Repository Flask app static files are not served

Tags: flask, pythonanywhere

I have invested time in getting a solution to this seemingly simple problem, but it seems the problem is coming from Pythonanywhere server as I have run the app successfully on Gooogle App Engine.

I have set static folder path as stated [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingStaticFiles) and I must point out that what I have done is:
For example, a CSS file is expected to be found at  `xxxxx.pythonanywhere.com/static/custom-css/abcdef.css`;
I set the URL to be:  `/static`;
I set the Directory to be: `/var/www/repos/equimolar/EquimolarBlog/equimolar_blog/static`

Please, can someone point out what I have been ignorantly doing wrong?
Again, why does one still have to manually set static files locations when it would have been taken care of in the program itself, after all, it runs perfectly on localhost and such extra bottle-neck are not needed on other platforms, like GAE?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get this fixed:

The issue is that there is a restriction not stated [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingStaticFiles),
Forget the way you reference your static files in your code, the static files are always expected on a lower case path when not explicitly mapped from the app dashboard on pythonanywhere.

Here is what I meant:
Say, a file is referenced from the app `src='/static/Custom-CSS/Files/abc.css'`
But on the disk, it is actually at `/var/www/repos/equimolar/EquimolarBlog/equimolar_blog/static/Custom-CSS/Files/abc.css'`

What pythonanywhere says is that the mapping could be:
`/static/ | /var/www/repos/equimolar/EquimolarBlog/equimolar_blog/static/`
Unfortunately, the file is being requested from: `/var/www/repos/equimolar/EquimolarBlog/equimolar_blog/static/custom-css/files/abc.css'` despite the fact that the casing had been taken care of from the app itself.

The current solution I used was just to change my folder names to all lower-cases.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- are you sure it's not the framework that's lower-casing your link?  I just set up a website with the static file mapping `/static/` -> `/home/giles/mysite/static`, and then created a file `/home/giles/mysite/static/Foo/Bar/something.txt`.  The file was accessible at `http://giles.pythonanywhere.com/static/Foo/Bar/something.txt`, as expected.